# Divide image into blocks

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I am using code to list image pixels with important information for later use - Red, Green, Blue, X, Y.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread

im = imread("image.jpg") 

indices = np.dstack(np.indices((im.shape[:2])))
data = np.concatenate((im, indices), axis=-1)
print data
```

printed data:

```
        R   G   B    X   Y
    [[[237 233 234   0   0]
      [235 231 232   0   1]
      [243 234 237   0   2]
      ..., 
      [236 232 233   0 507]
      [233 229 230   0 508]
      [236 232 233   0 509]]
```

But it prints whole image data plain not in blocks. How to get this data in 2x2 blocks, 4 pixels information in block? Like this:

```
    R   G   B    X   Y
[[[237 233 234   0   0]
  [235 231 232   0   1]
  [243 234 237   0   2]
  [243 234 257   0   3]]
```

Comment: 2x2 block has the following indices X = [0, 0, 1, 1], Y = [0, 1, 1, 0]. and not as you mentioned

Comment: or maybe X = [0, 0, 1, 1], Y = [0, 1, 0, 1]

Comment: and also the output is 4d because every 2x2 block in the image has 4x5 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following to your code:

```
a = data[::2, ::2, :]
b = data[::2, 1::2, :]
c = data[1::2, ::2, :]
d = data[1::2, 1::2, :]
e = np.stack([a, b, c, d], axis=3)
print(e)
```

Using my image:

```
     R    G    B     X    Y
[[[  47  124  206    0    0]
  [  52  124  206    0    1]
  [  53  126  205    0    2]
  ..., 
  [  74  129  211    0 1021]
  [  73  130  211    0 1022]
  [  69  132  211    0 1023]]

 [[  47  124  206    1    0]
  [  51  123  205    1    1]
  [  53  126  205    1    2]
  ..., 
  [  75  130  212    1 1021]
  [  73  130  211    1 1022]
  [  69  130  210    1 1023]] ...
```

turns to:

```
[[[[  47   52   47   51]   R
   [ 124  124  124  123]   G
   [ 206  206  206  205]   B
   [   0    0    1    1]   X
   [   0    1    0    1]]  Y

  [[  53   58   53   58]   R
   [ 126  125  126  125]   G
   [ 205  204  205  204]   B
   [   0    0    1    1]   X
   [   2    3    2    3]]  Y

  [[  64   71   64   70]   R
   [ 127  126  127  127]   G
   [ 206  208  206  208]   B
   [   0    0    1    1]   X
   [   4    5    4    5]]  Y

  ...,
```

Comment: Thanks Ophir it seems done exactly what I need, please could you check I understand output correctly first 3 values R,G,B what for stands 4th value? Bottom entries is X and Y?

  R     G    B     ?
[[237 235 238 237]
   [233 231 234 233]
   [234 232 235 234]
   [  0   0   1   1] X
   [  0   1   0   1]] Y
      R     G    B    ?
  [[243 240 244 240]
   [234 231 235 231]
   [237 234 238 234]
   [  0   0   1   1] X
   [  2   3   2   3]] Y